# If no blank lines preceding an outline heading `**`, then insert one blank line

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Could someone please give me a hand further defining my org outline cleanup function.  I am looking to have one blank line between each outline heading beginning with `**`, taking into consideration both possibilities -- i.e., there might be no blank lines (which means we need to insert one); and, there might be too many blank lines (which means we need to delete the extra ones).  The situation with no blank lines (where we need to insert one) is what is missing from the function.

The outline may be several levels deep and there is no way of accurately predicting what will be at the ending of an outline section, so we need to focus on patterns only at the beginning of the heading to define the function -- e.g., if only `\n[*][*]`, but not `\n\n[*][*]`, then insert `\n`.

```
(defun lawlist-cleanup ()
  "If there are no blank lines preceding an outline heading `**`, then insert one
blank line.  If there are more than one blank line, then delete the extras."
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (save-excursion
    (while (re-search-forward "\n\n\n[*][*]" nil t)
      (left-char 3)
      (delete-blank-lines))))
```

---

EDIT:  Here is the updated function based upon the generous help provided by both juanleon and Bruce Connor.  It handles the situation of first and second level headings, with an extra blank line for first level headings.

```
(defun lawlist-cleanup-second-draft ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion 
    (replace-regexp "\n+\\*\\* " "\n\n** " nil (point-min) (point-max))
    (replace-regexp "\n+\\* " "\n\n\n* " nil (point-min) (point-max))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with @juanleon answer, but here's another method that should work (just to show off the power of regexps :-D).

```
(save-excursion 
 (replace-regexp "[ 
]+\\*\\* " "\n\n** " nil (point-min) (point-max)))
```

*Note: that's a space and a new-line inside the square brackets.*

Comment: Thank you -- I'll try it out later this evening and post a follow-up.

Comment: I'm going to go with this answer, with the only change being an `\n` instead of the literal hard return in brackets so that I can keep the line of code together.  I made a second line of code similar to the first one, so that I can take care of headings with one asterisk and also headings with two asterisks.  I'll post the updated code below my original question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using `delete-blank-lines` is that its behavior depends on the number of blank lines around point.  Here is an very inelegant way to solve the problem:

```
(save-excursion
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (while (re-search-forward "^[*][*]" nil t)
    (forward-line 0)
    (newline)
    (forward-line -1)
    (delete-blank-lines)
    (delete-blank-lines)
    (newline)
    (forward-line 1))))
```

It hurts my eyes a little and it does look more like a macro than a function, but I think that it does the job.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing how your function works, but it does seem to do the trick.  Perhaps this is because I was never trained to "think like a programmer".  I'll try it several times throughout the day to see if there are any exceptions / anomalies, and then place a check-mark for your answer.  Thank you so very much -- greatly appreciated!

Comment: I ended up going for the replace-regexp answer because I have an affinity for regexp.  Without your help, however, I would have spent all day obsessing about the function.  Thank you again for all your help.  :)