# How to remove just some tags in org-mode using a custom function

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Could anyone please give me a hand removing the tag(s) entitled `:event` or `:event:`, which may or may not, be present in a particular todo that is being marked finished.

If there is no additional tag present, then the form to be removed is `:event:`.  If there is an additional tag appended to the right, then the form to be removed is `:event` -- because the colon connected to the other tag would need to remain -- e.g., `:smith_john:`  I would like to use this function for all todo, even though some of the todo will **not** contain an `event` tag.

This is a little tricky because a normal search and replace would **not** be limited to just this one particular task within the todo list.  I am aware of a tag removal function relating to a change of state, but I would prefer to use my own removal function.

Here is an example of `:event` appended to another tag:

```
** Reference [#A] smith @ meeting; 08/09/2013; 8:30 a.m. :event:smith_john:
   DEADLINE: <2013-08-09 Fri 08:30 >  SCHEDULED: <2013-08-09 Fri >
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ToodledoID: 335265357
   :ToodledoFolder: EVENTS
   :Hash: 4a6b6cc7fbefa9b7695b12247bf84d15
   :END:
   These are some notes relating to the client named John Smith.
```

Here is an example of task that will not contain the `:event` or `:event:` tags.  The `none` function should nevertheless be able to close it out like the task above.

```
** Next Action [#D] 0 @ kid's birthday -- 07/18/1993 :lawlist:
   DEADLINE: <2014-07-18 Fri >
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ToodledoID: 332902470
   :ToodledoFolder: TASKS
   :Hash: e7cf177f187d47c8fa8ca882f2725305
   :END:
   These are some notes relating to a task without an event tag.
```

The following is a function I use to mark a todo as `None`, which when synchronized with Toodledo will be understood to be the equivalent of what is more commonly referred to as `completed` or `done`.  The word `Reference` in the task above is a Toodledo todo state that I have chosen to use for events on my calendar, and the word `Next Action` is what I use for tasks with a future deadline.

```
(defun none (&optional default-heading)
(interactive)
  (let ((lawlist-item default-heading)
          result)
      (unless lawlist-item
        (condition-case nil
            (progn 
              (org-back-to-heading t)
              (setq lawlist-item (elt (org-heading-components) 4)))
          )
       )
  (org-todo "None")
  (org-priority ?E)
  (org-schedule 'remove)
  (org-deadline 'remove)
  (org-set-property "ToodledoFolder" "DONE")
  (setq org-archive-save-context-info nil)
  (setq org-archive-location "/Users/HOME/.0.data/*TODO*::* DONE")
  (org-archive-subtree)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (re-search-forward "^\* DONE" nil t)
     (condition-case err
         (progn
           (org-sort-entries t ?a)
           (lawlist-org-cleanup) ) ;; a custom pagination function.
       (error nil))
  (re-search-forward lawlist-item nil t)
  (beginning-of-visual-line) 
  (org-cycle-hide-drawers 'all)
  ))
```

---

EDIT:  Here are the clean-up functions used in the above `none` function, just in case anyone was interested in a complete solution to close out a particular todo in this manner:

```
(defun delete-trailing-blank-lines-at-end-of-file ()
       "Deletes all blank lines at the end of the file, even the last one"
       (interactive)
       (save-excursion
         (save-restriction
           (widen)
           (goto-char (point-max))
           (delete-blank-lines)
           (let ((trailnewlines (abs (skip-chars-backward "\n\t"))))
             (if (> trailnewlines 0)
                 (progn
                   (delete-char trailnewlines)))))))

(defun lawlist-org-cleanup ()
(interactive)
(save-excursion 
(replace-regexp "\n+\\*\\* " "\n\n** " nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-regexp "\n+\\* " "\n\n\n* " nil (point-min) (point-max))
(replace-regexp "\n\t\s*" "\n   " nil (point-min) (point-max)) )
(delete-trailing-blank-lines-at-end-of-file) )
```

Comment: In case anyone was wondering about the custom clean-up function, Bruce Connor contributed to writing that code also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452056/if-no-blank-lines-preceding-an-outline-heading-then-insert-one-blank-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as point is on the headline, the following should work:

```
(when (search-forward-regexp ":event\\|event:" (line-end-position) t)
  (replace-match "")
  (when (and (looking-at ":$\\|: ") (looking-back " "))
     (delete-char 1)))
```

Comment: This looks like it should do the trick.  I'll give it a whirl and report back . . . thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could be interested by the following:

```
;; remove redundant tags of headlines (from David Maus)
(defun leuven--org-remove-redundant-tags ()
  "Remove redundant tags of headlines in current buffer.
A tag is considered redundant if it is local to a headline and inherited by
a parent headline."
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
    (save-excursion
      (org-map-entries
       '(lambda ()
          (let ((alltags (split-string
                          (or (org-entry-get (point) "ALLTAGS") "")
                          ":"))
                local inherited tag)
            (dolist (tag alltags)
              (if (get-text-property 0 'inherited tag)
                  (push tag inherited) (push tag local)))
            (dolist (tag local)
              (if (member tag inherited) (org-toggle-tag tag 'off)))))
       t nil))))
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this function.  It may come in handy somewhere down the road when using tags in the headlines of both parents and children.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove the tags when the state is changing to `DONE` (or equivalent), you can use the following:

```lisp
(defun zin/org-remove-tag (tag)
    "Removes `TAG' from current list of tags if present when todo
state is DONE."
  (when (org-entry-is-done-p)
    (org-toggle-tag tag 'off)))

(defun zin/remove-event ()
   "Removes `event' from list of tags when state is set to done."
  (zin/org-remove-tag "event"))

(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook 'zin/remove-event)
```

`(org-entry-is-done-p)` will either return the `DONE` state of the headline, or NIL if it is not marked as done.  `org-toggle-tag` will either toggle the current state of the tag, or set to `'on` or `'off` if provided with the optional argument (in this case `'off`).

The first function is generic for any given tag, while the second is specific for your desired 'event' tag.

Alternately you can use the following as your hook:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook '(lambda ()
                                               (zin/org-remove-tag "event")))
```

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer works well, the following code snippet uses `org-mode` functions to accomplish the same result -- `org-set-tags-to` can use a string or a list as its optional argument; and, no argument removes all tags.

```
(let (tags)
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (setq tags (org-element-property :tags (org-element-at-point))))
  (when (and tags (member "event" tags))
    (setq tags (delete "event" tags))
    (org-set-tags-to tags)))
```